# How can I view a number of user groups?

Tags: c, linux

How can I view a number of user groups?

I mean the implementation in C.

I wanted to use the [`getgrouplist()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html) function, but I want it to take the number of groups automatically.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should [edit] it to state precisely what you want to accomplish, e.g., what you mean by "a number of user groups" and "take the number of groups automatically." See [ask].

Comment: The `getgrouplist()` function gets a list of groups that a particular user (indentified by UID) belongs to.  The kernel will not (cannot?) allocate the memory for you; you have to predetermine how many groups you're willing to handle.  This isn't a serious memory usage issue. Even if group IDs were 8 bytes each (they're much more likely to be 4 bytes each), and even if you allocated up to 128 groups worth (which is more groups for a single user than most systems are likely to have), you're talking about 1 KiB memory. Allocate it and get on with life. But 'view a number of groups' is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an off the cuff program which seems to work on my macOS 10.14.1 system, which seems to be quite behind the times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int res = 0;
  int ng = 100;
  int gs[ng];
  res = getgrouplist("hacksaw", 20, gs, &ng);
  printf("num_grps: %d\nres: %d\n", ng, res);
}
```

Here's one which works on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main(void)
{
  int res = 0;
  int ng = 100;
  gid_t gs[ng];
  res = getgrouplist("hacksaw", 20, gs, &ng);
  printf("num_grps: %d\nres: %d\n", ng, res);
}
```

The size 100 was chosen arbitrarily to provide maybe enough space.

Comment: Note that you should provide an array of `gid_t` rather than `int`.

Comment: The prototype I'm refering to is "int getgrouplist(const char *name, int basegid, int *groups, int *ngroups);" Clang complains if you use gif_t. (I'm on macOS)

Comment: Hmmm…OK — interesting! I added the reference ([`getgrouplist()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html)) now in the question, and it stipulates `int getgrouplist(const char *user, gid_t group, gid_t *groups, int *ngroups);`.  You seem to have a different source.  It's a portability concern for anyone who needs to move the code between systems. The function is a Linux and BSD extension, AFAIK.  On macOS (which is based on BSD), the prototype is `int getgrouplist(const char *name, int basegid, int *groups, int *ngroups);`!  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Standards have uses. It's not in POSIX. If it were, it'd use `gid_t`.  It probably never will be in POSIX with the name `getgrouplist()` because there are incompatible precedents (you'll not see a standard `qsort_r()` for the same reason).  If it is standardized, it would use a different name.

Comment: Yeah, seems like macOS is a bit outdated in a bunch of its library. Adding some info...

Comment: Actually, the problem for BSD is that they were ahead of their time in adding the function, and then the world changed around them and their interface became antiquated but couldn't be changed for reasons of backwards compatibility.  This sort of thing is quite a common problem.

Comment: Yeah, an amusing addition to the Linux man page: "This function is nonstandard; it appears on most BSDs.", which feels ever so much like "don't look at me, man, I didn't do it!"

Comment: @HackSaw: The Linux man pages project tries to *document* the interfaces and the standards or systems where they are defined; it is not an authority of any sort.